# Can't Serve Static HTML File with Express / Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am using Express with Node and then building a React app with this which is single page, except one static HTML file.

I have this working locally, so when I go to `localhost:3000/static-file.html`, I can see the file. But this doesn't work in production.

I can't even hit any of the test `console.log` statements, so I know that nothing is being hit when requesting `static-file.html`. Please see below part of my `app.js` file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.get('/static-file.html', function (req, res) {
    console.log('test1');
  });
  app.get('static-file.html', function (req, res) {
    console.log('test2');
  });
  app.get('static-file', function (req, res) {
    console.log('test3');
  });
  app.get('/static-file', function (req, res) {
    console.log('test4');
  });

  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}
```

When I go to production-site.com/static-file.html - I just see the index still, unlike with localhost.

Can anybody help me on that? Thanks so much.

Comment: you have to send the response in the end. after console please do res.send({}) or res.render(static-file.html);

Comment: @MohitTilwani But nothing is appearing in the console to say that the `console.log()` statement is even being hit, I should see something in console if the `app.get()` statement is working, no? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Your `get()` calls would all end up in timeouts. If you really want them to just log stuff, then you need to add a third argument to them and call the `next` callback: `app.get('/static-file.html', function(req, res, next){ console.log('whatever'); next(); })`

Comment: Got it, thanks. Unfortunately, none of them are being hit. It looks like `/` is always being hit, after further testing. Maybe I'm going about this wrongly. I just have no idea how else to get this working.

Comment: Ur sure that process.env.NODE_ENV is equal to production in your environnement ? Do app.get("*", function(req, res){ console.log("ok"); return res.status(200).json({});}); if you don't see the log or the response you've an issue with the value of process.env.NODE_ENV or the request is caught before by another handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try something like this:
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const path = require('path');

    // the __dirname is the current directory from where the script is running
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/build/index.html'))
    })

    /* Here build is the production build directory and index.html is the main html page to show */
```